# Unknown validator: 'ForbidChangingValidator'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I spend few hours trying to find solution of my problem, but lost any hope to understood what i am done wrong.

`Rails 4.2.6`

my model:

`app/models/component.rb`

```
class Component < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name, presence: true,
                 uniqueness: true,
            forbid_changing: true #TODO [VS] Fix custom validator autoload

  validates :label, presence: true,
                  uniqueness: true
end
```

my validator:

```
class ForbidChangingValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if record.send "#{attribute}_changed?".to_sym
      record.errors[attribute] << options[:message] || t(:changing_forbidden)
    end
  end
end
```

when try reload the page i got error:
`Unknown validator: 'ForbidChangingValidator'`

```
ArgumentError - Unknown validator: 'ForbidChangingValidator':
  activemodel (4.2.6) lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:120:in `rescue in block in validates'
  activemodel (4.2.6) lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:117:in `block in validates'
  activemodel (4.2.6) lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:113:in `validates'
  app/models/component.rb:6:in `<class:Component>'
  app/models/component.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
  repositor (0.6.0) lib/repositor/active_record.rb:6:in `initialize'
```

but when i am trying to call this validator from console i got:
`!! #<ArgumentError: A copy of Component has been removed from the module tree but is still active!>`

I found a lot of messages about thig issue, but can't to resolve mine.

Please, help somebody....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue. It's about naming policy. It strange ways rails try inflect the validator name.

I renamed my validator to `ForbidChangesValidator` and file also.
Everything goes great.

Thx all for attention.

Answer (score 1):

Custom validations using using ActiveModel::EachValidator need to be declared in the root namespace or "core" autoload paths *(however you want to define these directories)*.

For example:
*(YES means will work and NO means won't work)*

`app/validations` => **YES** since it is a new dir off of app/ it qualifies for root namespace

`app/models` => **YES** since it is a core directory

`app/models/concerns` => **YES** since it is a core directory

`app/models/validations` => **NO** Requires name spacing since it is a child directory off a core one.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the server fixed the issue for me, since everything else was right in place

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you defined `ForbidChangingValidator` at `app/validators/forbid_changing_validator.rb` and add the configuration to:

**config/application.rb**

```
# add custom validators path
config.autoload_paths += %W["#{config.root}/app/validators/"]
```

Comment: All folders in the `app` folder are autoloaded by default - you do not need to add it to the autoload path.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely, this would be an option to try!